# EditText With TextView Prompt

Tags: android, android-edittext

I was wondering if someone could help me create an EditText box with the specific shape as shown:

[image]

In other words, I want to have a TextView explaining what the EditText is for, in this case, a title, and to have the EditText box wrap around it as shown in red in the picture.

Thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: why not just use android:hint="purpose of text input" on your EditText?

Comment: I'm already using the hint to write a little more information about what I want the user to input - I just selected "Title" for an example.

Comment: you will have to write a custom view for this behavior

Comment: Alright, thanks for letting me know!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll probably want to use [LeadingMarginSpan.Standard](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/style/LeadingMarginSpan.Standard.html) to simply indent the first line of the `EditText` by the width of the title label, assuming the font sizes of the label and the editable text are the same.

If your issue is also concerning the borders then put a red border all around the `EditText`, make the label background solid white, and only show borders on the right and bottom sides of the label.

Answer (score 1):

No ready-made component for that. You can [implement your own](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/custom-components.html), use [hint](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#attr_android:hint) as suggested by @inner_class7 or a [cooler version of it](https://github.com/wrapp/floatlabelededittext)

Comment: Thanks for the links, I'll look into making my own :)

Answer (score 0):

I just want to be sure. Why you don't use the android:hint. (xml)

```
android:hint="The sentence appears into you box"
```

Comment: I wanted to include some other information as a hint, but thank you anyway :)